# Symfony2 and browserconfig.xml

Tags: php, symfony

Recently I deployed a application using Symfony2 framework. Since then, I realise in the logs there are 404s trying to find browserconfig.xml in my root directory.

I read it here "[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn320426(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn320426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)" that I can input this line so that IE11 will stop looking for the browserconfig.xml:

`<meta name="msapplication-config" content="none"/>`

However, it has been 2 days since I added that line but I am still getting errors looking for browserconfig.xml in my logs. It is very annoying.

Can anyone advice how to get rid of it please?

Thanks!

Comment: `touch web/browserconfig.xml`

Comment: Just create a blank file. No more 404s

Comment: I just added it. I will monitor the logs. Thank you.

Comment: Or you could actually use the file, if you wanted. That would have IE display your site's logo nicely when someone pins your site. You could do it manually but there's also [realfavicongenerator.net](http://realfavicongenerator.net/) that generates a set of files, including favicons in multiple dimensions and the `browserconfig.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your markup:

```
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="none"/>
```

or

You can add in a blank browserconfig.xml in the root of your site

or

You can use both at the same time (although there's no point in adding the meta tag as the blank file is enough to fool IE11.

Comment: should read <meta name="msapplication-config" content="none"> for the first one... sorry I'm new here